# Winforms get key pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

I have a form with some labels and two buttons, buttons are Yes and No.

For some reason I cannot get whether the user has pressed y or n keys on the form. If I use the same event for a textbox for example it works just fine.

```
private void Form2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Y)
            {
                btnYes.PerformClick();
            }
        }
```

Seems like that event never fires.
Why is that?

Comment: Why don't do a little bit of search before asking? See [results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=never+fires.&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs&gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=jMs6U4jqMYHY8geY-IHoAw&gws_rd=cr#channel=rcs&q=keydown+never+fires+c%23&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official)

Comment: btnYes.Text = "&Yes";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1 :** You need to set `KeyPreview` Property of the Form to `true`.

Try This:

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

**Solution 2:** But i would suggest you to override the `ProcessCmdKey()` method as below

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
  if (keyData == Keys.Y) {
   btnYes.PerformClick();
    return true;
  }
  return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```